# jQuery Confirm Replacement In A Simple Situation

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, confirm

how can i replace the code below with this jQuery Confirm :
[jQuery Alert Dialogs (Alert, Confirm, & Prompt Replacements)](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/12/jquery-alert-dialogs/)

and code :

```
OnClientClick="javascript:if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this row?')){return false;}
```

and jQuery's Confirm code :

```
jConfirm('Can you confirm this?', 'Confirmation Dialog', function(r) {
    jAlert('Confirmed: ' + r, 'Confirmation Results');
});
```

i test many ways with no results...
thanks in advance

Comment: There is no way of implementing it without making significant changes to your code, such as not using an `OnClientClick` to do it.

Comment: Instead of OnClientClick how about registering events using `addEventListener()`?

Comment: hi, but that OnClientClick is necessary. what changes?

Comment: `element.addEventListener('click',doSomething,false);` this will register a click event to `element` and perform `doSomething`.

Comment: that OnClientClick is for a linkbutton inside a TemplateColumn (inside Telerik -> RdaGrid)!

Comment: OnClientClick is simply `('#MyButton').click()` or a simple registered event using `addEventListener, just a different way of doing things.

Comment: @MoonLight Right, it's necessary because of your backend. That's why i said it's going to take significant changes to your code, possibly even changes to the server-side code. It can't be done inside of an onclick attribute because it is going to require preventing the event and then manually performing the action that it does.

Comment: ok, whould you please show me that as a answer!